# Circuit with coupled inductors, need help with mesh equations

Tags: inductance

Are the mesh equations in the image below correct? It gets a little tricky with the mutual inductance and my textbook gives no solution (American textbooks..). Click the image below for a larger view.

[image]

Comment: Damn it's a bit small, gonna make it bigger

Comment: If you can't see try zooming in with ctrl + forward scroll on mouse :P

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong sign of \$j3I_2\$ or \$j3I_1\$ in the wquations.
cause mutual flux comes from  other inductor  goes directly through the opposite direction of one's own flux. So your equations should be:
$$10\angle0 + j5I_1 - j9(I_1-I_2) + j3I_2 = 0 $$ 
$$28I_2 + j6I_2 -j3(I_1-I_2) -j9(I_1-I_2) + j3I_2=0$$